# PasteButton shows "Allow Paste" prompt

Tags: ios, swiftui, uipasteboard

I added a PasteButton to my SwiftUI app, but it still shows the "Allow Paste" prompt when tapped. After fighting this problem for half a day without success, I created a new SwiftUI app in Xcode and added this code from [PasteButton documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/pastebutton/):

```
@State private var pastedText: String = ""

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        PasteButton(payloadType: String.self) { strings in
            pastedText = strings[0]
        }
        Divider()
        Text(pastedText)
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

This works as expected in the Simulator: when I copy text, the button looks enabled and there is no prompt when I tap it - the text is pasted directly. When I copy something else, say an image, the button looks disabled.

When I run this sample app on a device and copy text, the button still looks disabled. When I tap it, the prompt "Allow Paste" appears. If I tap "Allow", the text is pasted. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug in your code, but rather a default setting by Apple. You can go to your iPhone's system settings and select your app there. There should be the option "Paste from other apps". Select "Allow" and the alert will no longer be displayed. The default setting is "Ask", which triggers the alert every time.

Comment: This is the behavior that you get when you make a custom Paste button that accesses the UIPasteboard. When you use the system PasteButton, then you don't need to allow anything in the settings - paste works without showing the "Allow Paste" prompt.